# Convexity of integral trajectories of rational vector field

Tags: cv.complex-variables, rational-functions

Suppose we have a vector field determined by a rational function,
of the form
$$
R(z) = \alpha i z + \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{c_j}{z-r_j}
$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and the other constants are in $\mathbb{R}$.
That is, for each point $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $R(z)$ gives a complex number which we interpret as a vector. Note that with this particular choice, the *integral curves*, (curves following the field), look almost like large circles far away from the origin. This is due to
$\infty$ being neither repelling nor attracting (since $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$).
See the attached figure for an example.

[image: Vector field]

Suppose now we have a closed integral curve $\gamma$, where all zeros and poles of $R(z)$
are in the interior. Let $\gamma_0$ be the smallest (intuitively) such integral curve.

Far away from the origin, $\gamma$ is more or less a circle, and thus convex. Now, as we 'shrink' $\gamma$, at some point (as in our figure), the integral curve cease to be convex.

Now, as $\gamma$ shrinks and gets more similar to $\gamma_0$,
we go from convex to non-convex.

**Is it possible that we go from non-convex back to convex again?**

Phrased in a different manner: let $\gamma$ be a non-convex integral curve containing all zeros and poles of $R(z)$. Can there be a (smaller) integral curve $\gamma^*$ inside $\gamma$,
which also contains all zeros and poles, but with  $\gamma^*$ being convex?